# How do I keep from leaving the screen?

Tags: android, xamarin, imageview, zooming

I do not speak English well.

We apologize if you do not understand the question.

```
LinearLayout _Main_Contact_Layout;
FrameLayout _Main_Frame; 
ImageView _Main_Background;
private List<string> _DrawerList_Item;
private ListView _DrawerList;

float _X, _Y;
float _XX, _YY;
int offset = 0, duration = 100;
float scaleX = 1.0f, scaleY = 1.0f;
float maxZoomLimit = 2.6f, minZoomLimit = 1.0f;

public bool OnTouch(View v, MotionEvent e)
{
    switch (e.Action)
    {
        case MotionEventActions.Down:

            _X = e.GetX();
            _Y = e.GetY();

            float _Start_X = 760, _Start_Y = 160;
            float _End_X = 1150, _End_Y = 490;

            WindowManagerLayoutParams _Params = new WindowManagerLayoutParams();
            _Params.X = (int)e.RawX;
            _Params.Y = (int)e.RawY;

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
            View _Popup = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Custom_Popup, null);

            PopupWindow _Window = new PopupWindow(_Popup, WindowManagerLayoutParams.WrapContent, WindowManagerLayoutParams.WrapContent);
            _Window.SetBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
            _Window.OutsideTouchable = true;

            TextView _SetupX = (TextView)_Popup.FindViewById(Resource.Id.x_text);
            TextView _SetupY = (TextView)_Popup.FindViewById(Resource.Id.y_text);

            _SetupX.Text = "X 좌표 : " + _X.ToString("#.##");
            _SetupY.Text = "Y 좌표 : " + _Y.ToString("#.##");

            DrawerLayout _lstDrawer = (DrawerLayout)v.FindViewById(Resource.Id._DrawerLayout);


            if(_Start_X > _X | _Start_Y > _Y | _End_X < _X | _End_Y < _Y )
            {
                _Window.Focusable = true;
                _Window.ShowAsDropDown(_Popup, _Params.X, _Params.Y);
                _Window.ShowAtLocation(_Popup, GravityFlags.Left | GravityFlags.Top, 0, 0);
                _lstDrawer.CloseDrawer((int)GravityFlags.Left);
            }

            else if (_Start_X < _X & _Start_Y < _Y & _End_X > _X & _End_Y > _Y & !_lstDrawer.IsDrawerOpen((int)GravityFlags.Left))
            {
                _lstDrawer.OpenDrawer((int)GravityFlags.Left);
                _Window.ShowAsDropDown(_Popup, _Params.X, _Params.Y);
                _Window.ShowAtLocation(_Popup, GravityFlags.Left | GravityFlags.Top, 0, 0);
            }

            else if (_lstDrawer.IsDrawerOpen((int)GravityFlags.Left))
            {
                _lstDrawer.CloseDrawer((int)GravityFlags.Left);
            }

            break;


        case MotionEventActions.Move:

            _XX = e.GetX() - _X;
            _YY = e.GetY() - _Y;

            //_Main_Background.SetX(_Main_Background.GetX() + _XX);
            //_Main_Background.SetY(_Main_Background.GetY() + _YY);

            _X = e.GetX();
            _Y = e.GetY();


            if (scaleX > 1.0f && scaleY > 1.0f)
            {
                _MoveToX(_XX);
                _MoveToY(_YY);

                Console.WriteLine("_XX : " + _XX.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("_YY : " + _YY.ToString());
            }

            break;
    }

    return true;
}

private void _MoveToX(float xX)
{
    float futureX = _Main_Background.GetX() + _XX;
    if (futureX > 0 | futureX < 500)
    {
        _Main_Background.SetX(futureX);
    }
}

private void _MoveToY(float yY)
{
    float futureY = _Main_Background.GetY() + _YY;
    if (futureY > 0 | futureY < 500)
    {
        _Main_Background.SetY(futureY);
    }
}



private void _Zoom_In(View v)
{
    if (scaleX < maxZoomLimit && scaleY < maxZoomLimit)
    {
        Animation animation = new ScaleAnimation(scaleX, (scaleX + 0.2f), scaleY, (scaleY + 0.2f), _X, _Y);
        scaleX += 0.2f;
        scaleY += 0.2f;
        animation.Interpolator = new DecelerateInterpolator();
        animation.Duration = duration;
        animation.StartOffset = offset;
        animation.FillAfter = true;
        v.StartAnimation(animation);
    }
}

private void _Zoom_Out(View v)
{
    if (scaleX > minZoomLimit && scaleY > minZoomLimit)
    {
        Animation animation = new ScaleAnimation(scaleX, (scaleX - 0.2f), scaleY, (scaleY - 0.2f), _X, _Y);
        scaleY -= 0.2f;
        scaleX -= 0.2f;
        animation.Interpolator = new DecelerateInterpolator();
        animation.Duration = duration;
        animation.StartOffset = offset;
        animation.FillAfter = true;
        v.StartAnimation(animation);
    }
}
```

I am worried about this for about a week.

How do I keep from leaving the screen?

Adjusting the scale? How do I touch the scale?

1. Zoom in and Zoom out using the Button
   -> resolution
2. Moving images with Zoom in using Button
   -> resolution
3. If you move it after Zoom in, start with moving the image to a strange place.
   -> resolution
4. Layout out of range
   -> resolution
5. Move only within layout range (Unresolved)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify the `if` condition in your `_MoveTo` method. The `x`, `y` is the coordinate of the top left corner of your view. Calculate the width and height of the `imageview`, make sure the `x` and `y` value is smaller than 0 and not smaller than the value of screenwidth minus the imageview width.

For example:

```
    private void _MoveToX(float xX)
    {
        float futureX = _Main_Background.GetX() + xX;
        if (futureX <=0 && futureX >=YourScreenWidth -(_Main_Background.Width * scaleX))
        {
            _Main_Background.SetX(futureX);
            Console.WriteLine("futureY : " + (_Main_Background.Height * scaleX).ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("futureX : " + futureX.ToString());
        }
    }

    private void _MoveToY(float yY)
    {
        float futureY = _Main_Background.GetY() + yY;
        if (futureY <= 0 && futureY >=YourScreenHeight- (_Main_Background.Height * scaleY))
        {
            _Main_Background.SetY(futureY);
            Console.WriteLine("futureY : " + (_Main_Background.Height * scaleY).ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("futureY : " + futureY.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me.
Current problem I want to show you a video, but is there any way?

Comment: Sorry, I am not good at English, So I did not explain correctly....
I want to show you the current problem by video
Is there any way to send it out somewhere? For example, something like an email

Comment: @MingiKim You could upload your video to the Google Drive and give me the shareable link. And it's better if you could also provide the project.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1DQymB3xyWLHZ7DtVjWhs5iwZm96SSoeG
Is this possible? Class Cord, LayoutCord is also included. I'd like you to look at it.

Comment: There is a similar phenomenon to the video I showed you before.
Let's think more about the layout and the code.
I'll try to worry more once!
If you do not mind, Can you help me if you ask me again later?
If you post a question, I will link to the answer in this article.

Comment: @MingiKim Feel free to contact me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173117/discussion-between-mingi-kim-and-billy-liu-msft).